# Python CAN bus notifier

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, can-bus

I am trying to connect to the CAN-bus of my car. The connection is working and the data is printing to the terminal without any problems.

```
bus = can.interface.Bus("can0", bustype="socketcan")
notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [can.Printer()])
```

I am using Python Can 2.2 and python 3.7.

I want to add a new listener with some sort of switch-case statement on the can.dlc. Would the pseudocode below be the best way to do that?

```
import can

def parse_data(can):
    SingleCanFrame = can.Message
    print(SingleCanFrame)
    if SingleCanFrame.arbitration_id == 304:    #car voltage
        #convert data 
        #save to DB table 1
    elif SingleCanFrame.arbitration_id == 400:  #car speed
        #convert data 
        #save to DB table 2
    elif SingleCanFrame.arbitration_id == 401:  #car tachometer
        #convert data 
        #save to DB table 3
    else:
        #save to DB errorlog
    
bus = can.interface.Bus("can0", bustype="socketcan")    
notifier = can.Notifier(bus, [parse_data(can)])
```

Comment: dlc is data length code between 0 and 8. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Data_frame).

Comment: Sorry, i meant the arbitration_id

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, that would be a fine way to do that.

However, if you would like to express your intent more clearly, a dictionary would be helpful:

```
CAR = {"voltage": 304, "speed": 400, "tachometer": 401} # capital var name as this a constant var
```

Then you could just refer to the values as `if SingleCanFrame.dlc == CAR["voltage"]:` which is less error-prone.

Comment: A dictionary would indeed be a excellent way to do it. Would it make sense to further split the functionality into functions?

Comment: I'd need some more context to speak for that on the 'functionality' and 'functions'. Though the rule of thumb is that any code that is reusable or will be reused with minor changes should be put in a function - which the "convert data" and "save to DB table" could be candidates.