# Problem configuring a Python-Can listener

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, listener, can-bus, python-can

I'm relatively new to python and am attempting to make a new program to interface with a canbus. I've been working my way through the documentation and some examples for python-can using the SocketCAN interface and I'm running into some issues.

I've confirmed the hardware works appropriately. I have a separate device to transmit a test-pattern onto the CANbus and when using a default listener "can.Printer()" the expected messages being transmitted onto the CANbus are correctly printed in terminal.

My next step was to create a new listener function that will ultimately process the received messages from the CANbus (the msg_rx_routine function in my code). When using the code I have now, usually the first received CAN message gets printed, but then I a callback error of "non type" object is not callable.

My hardware:
-rPi CM4 + I/O expension board
-MCP2515 breakout board

The test code:

```
import can
import time
import os

#--------define support functions
"""
FUNCTION:       message receive routine
@ARG can_bus:   passed can object
RETURN:         none
"""
def msg_rx_routine(can_bus):
    rx_msg = can_bus.recv()
    print(rx_msg)

#--------CANBUS init
os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")         #bring up can0 interface at 500kbps
time.sleep(0.05)                                                            #brief pause
CAN1 = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan')               #instance CAN object
#TODO: configure CAN connection (masks, etc)
#CAN1_listener = can.Printer()                                               #assign default "printer" listener to print to terminal
CAN1_listener = msg_rx_routine(CAN1)                                        #assign message handler function as a listener
CAN1_notifier = can.Notifier(CAN1, [CAN1_listener])                         #assign listener to notifier


def main():
    while True:
        pass        #just dummy loop to wait on a break command

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The resultant error:
[Console Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnVWy.png)

I feel like I'm obviously misunderstanding something at the core concept of the "listener/notifier" functionality of this works and it's got me stumped. How I'm (trying) to understand this now would be like how an IRQ request in C-code for a micro-contoller would work. Given the interrupt (notifier) it will call some linked function (listener).

As previously stated, what I'm trying to achieve is:
-wait for message
-on message receive, call function
-function does something with the message

I see there's a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818333/python-can-bus-notifier) where someone is doing the same thing. I (think) they're passing the `parse_data` function just the `can` data type, correct? It doesn't make sense to me though why you'd pass just the generic `can` type to the function, when it would make more sense to say WHICH bus you're looking for the message on. I'm not sure if that's just me mis-understanding something or non-unique variable naming in many of the examples I've found.

EDIT-1:

After doing some more reading, I realize I mis-understood the original code in a pretty "doh" moment. The part `CAN1_listener = can.Printer()` in the code was just creating a new object, of the `can.Printer` class, which was then being assigned to the notifier. I've tried to make my own class to basically replicate that but I'm still having issues:

```
class can_msg_handler:
    def __init__(   self, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass
    def on_message_reveived(self, msg: can.Message) -> None:
        print(msg)
```

when using the new class with `CAN1_listener = can_msg_handler()` I now get a "object is not callable" error. Obviously more to read/learn with py so I'll keep at it.

EDIT-2:
updating the function as @mkreiger1 and @MSpiller suggested to the below and "attempt 2" works as intended. I'm still a bit confused as to why, since in a C/C++ sense you'd still have to input the arguments but it works. I'll try the class update and post back as well.

```
import can
import time
import os

#--------define support functions
"""
FUNCTION:       message receive routine
@ARG can_bus:   passed can object
RETURN:         none
"""
def msg_rx_routine(rx_msg):
    print(rx_msg)

class can_msg_handler:
    def __init__(   self, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass
    def on_message_reveived(self, msg: can.message) -> None:
        print(msg)

#--------CANBUS init
os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")         #bring up can0 interface at 500kbps
time.sleep(0.05)                                                            #brief pause
CAN1 = can.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan')               #instance CAN object
#TODO: configure CAN connection (masks, etc)
#CAN1_listener = can.Printer()                                              #attempt 1: packaged listener to print to terminal
CAN1_listener = msg_rx_routine                                              #attempt 2: call function when new message
#CAN1_listener = can_msg_handler()                                          #attempt 3: call function in class when new message
CAN1_notifier = can.Notifier(CAN1, [CAN1_listener])                         #assign listener to notifier

def main():
    while True:
        pass        #just dummy loop to wait on a break command

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Presumably you want to pass the function `msg_rx_routine` to `can.Notifier`. Instead, you call the function and pass its return value (which is `None`) to `can.Notifier`.

Comment: I'd like to execute the `msg_rx_routine` when there's a new message. From my understanding, the notifier will pass the message to the listeners when there's the new message.

I see what you're saying about the assignment of the return value now, though. I'm assuming that because `can.Printer()` is a class, it does not have that same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/listeners.html#can.Notifier) of `can.Notifier` each `listener` has to be either an instance of [can.Listener](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/listeners.html#can.Notifier) or a callable which takes a `can.Message` as first argument.

You could use your class `can_msg_handler` by making it inherit from `can.Listener`:

```py
class can_msg_handler(can.Listener):
    def __init__(   self, **kwargs) -> None:
        pass
    def on_message_received(self, msg: can.Message) -> None:
        print(msg)

...
CAN1_listener = can_msg_handler
```

or you pass the function `msg_rx_routine` as a listener, as @ mkrieger1 has pointed out:

```py
CAN1_listener = msg_rx_routine
```

Comment: Thanks for giving some additional detail. Python is new to me so I'm trying to crash-course my way through it a bit.

I was having a hard time wrapping my head around how to make a new call of the listener type, through using the `can.Listener` class. You answered that with the modification to the `can_msg_handler` class. Looking at the documentation for the `can.Printer` class appears then that it inherits the `MessageWriter` class, is that correct?

Comment: Secondly then, for passing the function as a listener, I tried that initially and was getting an error (the error in my OP). I'm assuming then that the issue was I was using a bus type (not the message type expected) as the first argument? 

I'm not finding explicitly (or am not understanding) where it says that in the documentation though. Is it at the 'The basic listener that can be called.....' part? I was confused since in the example `SomeListener()' didn't have any arguments being passed to it in the assignment.

Comment: I updated the function to `def msg_rx_routine(rx_msg)` and then also the listener line to `CAN1_listener = msg_rx_routine` and it works as intended. I'm a little lost on why though. In a C/C++ sense, I'd have to also specify WHAT it's being sent. Is that not required in python or what core functionality am i missing here?

Comment: @jungle_jim Answering from top to bottom: `can.Printer` inherits from `MessageWriter`, which in turn inherits from `can.Listener`.
For your second question, you are not required to specify the type if the function arguments in python. If you want however you can. The signature would then be: `def msg_rx_routing(rx_msg: Message)`. In your original question the problem was rather that you did not pass `msg_rx_routine`, but `msg_rx_routine(...)` as a listener. In C++ speak: you did not pass the function pointer, but the return value of the function execution.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. I don't know why but at the time that wasn't real clear to me but now thinking of it as a function pointed helped wrap my head around it. I've done some more reading on class inheritance and haven't tried that approach yet but I see the progression of the inheritance and the different options (like using the super.__init__ statement, etc.) Lots to learn yet but this has helped!